# The graph of inverse function $f^{-1}(y)$

Tags: plotting, graphics

Show that $f:I=(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$
 it follows that $$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
 \quad1-x & \text{ as } -1<x\leq 0,  \\ 
 \frac{{x}^{-1}+ \lfloor {x}^{-1}\rfloor}{1+{x}^{-1}+\lfloor {x}^{-1}\rfloor}& \text{  as    }     \quad0<x<1 ,
\end{cases}$$ 
and $\lfloor x\rfloor=$max{$n\in\mathbb{Z}$|$n\leq x$}.

We can proof the mapping $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow f(I)$is bijective,so let $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $f$ .

**I want use *$Mathematica$* to get $f^{-1}$,who can give me some details ?  Any help from you will be greatly appreciated!**

My effort:[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey:I will give my effort soon!

Comment: ParametricPlot[{f[x], x}, {x, -1, 1 - 10^-9}, 
 PlotRange -> {{.6, 2.05}, Automatic}, PlotPoints -> 200]

Comment: @Bob Hanlon:I need to get the graph of inverse function $f^{-1}(y)$,not the graph of $f(x).$

Comment: The plot of f[x] is the set of points {x, f[x]} over he domain; the inverse function is the set of points {f[x], x}.

Comment: @BobHanlon：I know that ,but How can I get the graph of inverse function $f^{-1} (y)$ use $Mathmatica$. `InverseFunction[f]`maybe do something useful to it!

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/inverse-of-function-including-hyperbolic-cotangent).

Answer (score 10):

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{
    {1 - x, -1 < x <= 0},
    {(1/x + Floor[1/x])/(1 + 1/x + Floor[1/x]),
     0 < x < 1}}];

Plot[InverseFunction[f][y], {y, f[1. - 10^-9], f[-1. + 10^-9]},
 PlotPoints -> 101,
 AxesOrigin -> {.6, 0}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{f[x], x},
 {x, -1, 1 - 10^-9},
 PlotRange -> {{.6, 2.05}, Automatic},
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 AxesOrigin -> {.6, 0}]
```

[image]

Note that the `ParametricPlot` is much faster.

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of ways to obtain an inverse.  Here is a common one.

Your Function

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1 - x, -1 < x <= 
     0}, {(x^-1 + Abs[x^-1])/(1 + x^-1 + Abs[x^-1]), 0 < x <= 1}}];
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: f[x]]

Its inverse, determine as described in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) to `FindRoot`

```
g[y_] := x /. FindRoot[f[x] - y, {x, 0}];
Plot[g[y], {y, 2/3, 2}]
```

[image: g[y]]

Comment: I want use `InverseFunction[f] `,but I get mistake! thanks a lot!

Comment: I misread your special symbol as `Abs`, not `Floor`.  I shall have a corrected answer for you in a few minutes.

Comment: :Many thanks! :)