# Fast method for getting the inverse function of the Hypergeometric function in Mathematica

Tags: special-functions, inverse

I didn't manage to obtain the inverse function for this frightening function:

```
t[a_] := Sqrt[3/(8 Pi GG)]*2/3 (1 + (a^(3 + 3 α) A)/const)^(1/(2 + 2α))(A + a^(-3 (1 + α))const)^(-(1/(2 + 2 α)))Hypergeometric2F1[1/(2 + 2 α), 1/(2 + 2 α),1 + 1/(2 + 2 α), -((a^(3 + 3 α) A)/const)]
```

I'm a beginner with Mathematica so I don't understand how to apply `ParametricPlot` described here [The graph of inverse function $f^{-1}(y)$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69862/the-graph-of-inverse-function-f-1y)

And failed attempt:

```
Assuming[A > 0 && α > 1 && const > 0 ,{Plot[InverseFunction[t][y], {y,t[1. - 10^-9], t[0. + 10^-9]}]}]
```

The important assumptions are `GG=6.67*10^(-11)`, `A>0`, `const>0`, `Alpha>1`.

I would be happy to get any help.

Comment: Probably you want:`GG = 6.67*10^(-11);
α = 2;
A = 1;
const = 1; 
f[y_] := Sqrt[3/(8 Pi GG)]*2/
   3 (1 + (y^(3 + 3 α) A)/const)^(1/(2 + 2 α)) (A + 
     y^(-3 (1 + α)) const)^(-(1/(2 + 
         2 α))) Hypergeometric2F1[1/(2 + 2 α), 
   1/(2 + 2 α), 
   1 + 1/(2 + 2 α), -((y^(3 + 3 α) A)/
      const)]; ParametricPlot[{f[y], y}, {y, 10^-9, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]`

Comment: Note that your `Plot[InverseFunction[t][y],...]` will work only when you assign numeric values to the parameters (e.g. `A`, `const`, etc.). This restriction has to do with `Plot` requiring numeric coordinates more than with `InverseFunction`: for instance, `Plot[a x, {x, 0, 1}]` produces a blank plot if `a` is undefined, but `InverseFunction[a # &]` works (tacitly assuming `a` is nonzero).

Comment: The `ParametricPlot` trick is simple enough, you just `ParametricPlot[{t[a],a},{a,fromthere,tothere}]` which will simply exchange the horizontal and vertical axis for you - but is it what you want?