# Inverse function and Integral: How to simplify this DSolve output?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I'm trying to `DSolve` these equations with each other:

```
q1[t_] := 3 (y'[t]/y[t])^2 - (1/(y[t]^3)) - (1/(y[t]^4)) - 1

q2[t_] := -2 y''[t]/y[t] - (y'[t]/y[t])^2 - (1/(3 y[t]^4)) + 1

q3[t_] := -3 (y''[t]/y[t] + (y'[t]/y[t])^2) + 1
```

When solving the first with the second by:

```
DSolve[{q1[t] == q2[t]}, y, t]
```

I get an output in the form:
[image]

While when solving the second with the third

```
DSolve[{q2[t] == q3[t]}, y, t]
```

I get:

[image]

Any idea how to interpret or simplify these outputs to be for example like:

[image]

I tried many initial conditions- they are so arbitrary for `y[t]` or `y'[t]`- but always have in terms of Integral or InverseFunction .

Any help about this will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the solution of these ODEs just can't be expressed without `InverseFunction` or `Integrate`? Do you have any reason to believe the solution can be transformed to something free of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[q2[t] - q3[t]]
```

(-1 + 6 y[t]^2 Derivative[1][y][t]^2 +
3 y[t]^3 (y^[Prime][Prime])[t])/(3 y[t]^4)

So the 3 y[t]^4 can be ignored for the solution.

The term

6 y[t]^2 y'[t]^2 + 3 y[t]^3 y''[t]

equals

y[t]D[y[t]^3, t, t].

Good practice is to entered the equation that are close to standards or standards.

So the homogenous equation can be solved by third root of a linear function.

The built-in [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html) works like this:

```
InverseFunction[c ArcTan][x]
```

InverseFunction[ArcTan c][x]

and

```
InverseFunction[ArcTan][x]
```

Tan[x]

It does chaining and works with numbers.

So the solution has to be dealt with by hand.

So the term in the InverseFunction of Your second DSolve problem does this:

```
Integrate[-3 ArcTanh[x/Sqrt[3 C[1] + x^2]] C[1] + 
  x Sqrt[3 C[1] + x^2], x]
```

-3 x ArcTanh[x/Sqrt[x^2 + 3 C[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html)]] C[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html) +
1/3 Sqrt[x^2 + 3 C[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html)] (x^2 + 12 C[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html))

The advantages of this strategy are not always visible to everybody.

The main problem in the q's are the inhomogeneities. The homogenous equation will give more closed form solutions.

[Variation of Parameters](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VariationofParameters.html)
[Method Of Variation Of Parameters For Second Order Linear Differentia](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MethodOfVariationOfParametersForSecondOrderLinearDifferentia/)
may lead to partly more closed form of solutions.

Since a lot power with ODE is stored in literature examples and equation collection these sources has to be made a requisite even for the word with the powerful Mathematica.

A look worth:
[equation world](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/software.htm)
and many more.

This question shows, how to deal in Mathematica with `InverseFunction`: [the-graph-of-inverse-function-f-1y](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69862/https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69862/the-graph-of-inverse-function-f-1y).
For     C[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html)==C[2](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VariationofParameters.html)==1:

```
Plot[InverseFunction[
   Inactive[Integrate][-((Sqrt[3] K[1]^2)/Sqrt[
      3 1 + K[1]^2 + K[1]^3 + K[1]^6]), {K[1], 1, #1}] &][t + 1], {t, 
  0, 10}]
```

[image: Plot]

[enter link description here](http://%3Cimg%20src=%22http://vg09.met.vgwort.de/na/a1a518cf7d1143849e3c0227d3bd82bd%22%20width=%221%22%20height=%221%22%20alt=%22%3E)

Answer (score 2):

With `DSolve` you get y[t] as an `InverseFunction` , diffucult to understand. Invert this function again with `Solve` to get t[y] in simple form you can plot with `ParametricPlot` .

```
f = q2[t] - q3[t] // Together // Numerator

dsol1 = DSolve[f == 0, y, t, 
   GeneratedParameters -> (ToExpression[
  StringJoin["c", ToString[#]]] &)]

(*   {{y -> Function[{t}, 
InverseFunction[-(1/2) Sqrt[
    3] (-3 c1 Log[#1 + Sqrt[3 c1 + #1^2]] + #1 Sqrt[
       3 c1 + #1^2]) &][c2 + t]]}, {y -> 
 Function[{t}, 
   InverseFunction[
  1/2 Sqrt[
    3] (-3 c1 Log[#1 + Sqrt[3 c1 + #1^2]] + #1 Sqrt[
       3 c1 + #1^2]) &][c2 + t]]}}   *)

t1[ys_, c1_, c2_] = t /. First@Solve[(y[t] /. dsol1[[1]]) == ys, t]

(*   -c2 - 1/2 Sqrt[3] (ys Sqrt[3 c1 + ys^2] - 3 c1 Log[ys + Sqrt[3 c1 + ys^2]])   *)

t2[ys_, c1_, c2_] = t /. First@Solve[(y[t] /. dsol1[[2]]) == ys, t]

(*   -c2 + 1/2 Sqrt[3] (ys Sqrt[3 c1 + ys^2] - 3 c1 Log[ys + Sqrt[3 c1 + ys^2]])   *)

Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[{{t1[ys, c1, c2], ys}, {t2[ys, c1, c2], 
ys}}, {ys, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotRange -> All], {{c1, 1}, 0, 5}, {c2, -4, 4}]
```

Comment: Hello.  May I ask in the last step after getting t(y), can we have y(t) again ? But as I asked in the main question simplified and understood as t(y) ?